# How can I print value of std::atomic<unsigned int>?

Tags: c++, printing, atomic, stdatomic

I am using `std::atomic<unsigned int>` in my program. How can I print its value using `printf`? It doesn't work if I just use `%u`. I know I can use `std::cout`, but my program is littered with `printf` calls and I don't want to replace each of them. Previously I was using `unsigned int` instead of `std::atomic<unsigned int>`, so I was just using `%u` in the format string in my `printf` call, and therefore printing worked just fine.

The error I'm getting when trying to print the `std::atomic<unsigned int>` now in place of the regular `unsigned int` is:

> `error: format ‘%u’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 2 has type ‘std::atomic<unsigned int>’ [-Werror=format=]`

Comment: it might help if you show us the code you have tried, and how it did not work (output or error message)

Comment: `std::atomic<>` has a `load()` member function for reading the value (atomically :-). You could use that one.

Comment: Do you really need an atomic variable? `std::atomic` is for ordering memory access to the variable for concurrency issues.

Comment: Yes AJG85, that is exactly what I'm using std::atomic for.

Comment: Please add a sample error or warning to the question for anyone googling this. Ex: `error: format ‘%u’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 2 has type ‘std::atomic<unsigned int>’ [-Werror=format=]`. I think this error applies to this question. It's my error right now, at least.

Comment: Fun fact: MSVC19.10 (VS2015) fails to reject `printf("%u", atomic_var)`.  https://godbolt.org/z/ceWvhKbvn shows it actually copies the `std::atomic<>` object to the stack, not just the underlying `T`.  (Unlike most implementations, when MSVC's `std::atomic` can't be lock-free, it includes a mutex in the object itself.  So `sizeof(atomic<big>) == 36` vs. 32 for the underlying struct, and we see it use 2x `movups` plus an extra 4-byte `mov`).  So bugs like this can exist in codebases that have only been tested with older MSVC.  Seems to be fixed in MSVC19.10 from VS2017 and later.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
template<typename BaseType>
struct atomic
{
    operator BaseType () const volatile;
}
```

Use a typecast to pull out the underlying value.

```
printf("%u", unsigned(atomic_uint));
```

Answer (score 28):

another option, you can use the atomic variable's [`load()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/load) method. E.g.:

```
std::atomic<unsigned int> a = { 42 };
printf("%u\n", a.load());
```